# Does armor break have any impact on gameplay?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

Does breaking your opponent's armor affect gameplay in any way or is it all aesthetics? Does wearing different armor affect anything?

Answer (score 5):

Armor breaking now appears only to occur on a KO, so it's a very different affect than in SCIV.  It no longer breaks your block or leaves you open to a critical finish.

Since armor doesn't add to your stats in this version, the destruction has no real effect.

Comment: So you're saying you no longer take additional damage by losing your armor?

Comment: @Kotsu Everything I've read says that... that it's become purely cosmetic.  As the game matures we might find out differently.

Comment: Even though there are no stats, having your armor broken might have some defensive penalties. Who knows....

Comment: @Maxx I completely leave the door open to this possibility, but at the moment the best info says no.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that having armor broken affects gameplay, given that it's possible to choose no armor for your character during creation.